# Copying and resizing image changes colors

Tags: php, image-processing, scale

Original

[image: Original]

Scaled

[image: Scaled]

I have a script that copies and resizes an image on the server. It scales really good but the color differs on the outputted file.

The quality is set to max, are there any other settings I can change to get a better copy?

[Example with original on top and scaled below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYACX.jpg)

```
$directory = 'path/to/directory';
$image_file = 'filename.extension';
$image = $directory.$image;
$destination = 'path/to/new/directory';

$source_size = getimagesize($image);

if ($source_size !== false) {

    switch($source_size['mime']) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
             $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
        break;
        case 'image/png':
             $source = imagecreatefrompng($image);
        break;
    }

    // Set a maximum height and width
    $width = 1280;
    $height = 2000;

    // Get old dimensions
    list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($image);

    $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

    if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
       $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
    } else {
       $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
    }

    // Resample
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

    switch($source_size['mime']) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
             imagejpeg($thumb, $destination.$image_file, 100);
        break;
        case 'image/png':
              imagepng($thumb, $destination.$image_file, 9);
        break;
    }
}
```

Below is a script that outputs some information about the two images

```
$file = 'original.jpg';
    $info = unpack('A8sig/Nchunksize/A4chunktype/Nwidth/Nheight/Cbit-depth/'.
        'Ccolor/Ccompression/Cfilter/Cinterface', 
        file_get_contents($file,0,null,0,29))
        ;
    print_r($info);


    $file = 'scaled.jpg';
    $info = unpack('A8sig/Nchunksize/A4chunktype/Nwidth/Nheight/Cbit-depth/'.
        'Ccolor/Ccompression/Cfilter/Cinterface', 
        file_get_contents($file,0,null,0,29))
        ;
    print_r($info);
```

**Output**

Original

```
Array ( [sig] => ÿØÿàJF [chunksize] => 1229324289 [chunktype] => , [width] => 19660800 [height] => 4292942560 [bit-depth] => 69 [color] => 120 [compression] => 105 [filter] => 102 [interface] => 0 )
```

Scaled

```
Array ( [sig] => ÿØÿàJF [chunksize] => 1229324289 [chunktype] =>  [width] => 65536 [height] => 4294836284 [bit-depth] => 67 [color] => 82 [compression] => 69 [filter] => 65 [interface] => 84 )
```

The original file (1080p) is 580K and the scaled file (720p) is 638K

Comment: take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611852/imagecreatefrompng-makes-a-black-background-instead-of-transparent

Comment: I don't think that it's a transparecy problem since my image is a jpeg.

Comment: What about but depht? Is it possible you are reducing the bit depth of the image?

Comment: @jnovacho Edited by question with included bit-depth

Comment: I don't know what library you are using, but from the $info it's one can tell, that the those two images are clearly different.
I would suggest to dig into the docs, and look into saving options. I would guess, the problem is writing images to disk, rather than resizing.