# Add transparent watermark into image

Tags: php

I need to add transparent watermark (transparency in final image - 80%). I created this function to handle it:

```
function ImageAddWatermark($im, $stamp, $onLeft, $onTop, $margin){       
        // $stamp = imagecreatformpng(...) -> GD resource?
        // not important part - it calculates position of watermark 
        if($onLeft){
            $orgX = $margin;
        } else {
            $orgX = imagesx($im)-$margin-imagesx($stamp);
        }

        if($onTop){
            $orgY = $margin;
        }else {
            $orgY = imagesy($im)-$margin-imagesy($stamp);
        }

        imagecopymerge($im, $stamp, $orgX, $orgY, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp), 50);

        return $im;
    }
```

Result of function:
[image: error]

But imagecopymerge returns black background instead of transparent. I even heard some opinions, that imagecopymerge isn't exactly the right thing for creating transparent watermarks...

So the question is: **"How can I add a transparent watermark (using alpha?) in jpeg photo?" How can I get rid of that black backgound?** (In original PNG file is transparent)

Comment: what is `$stamp` before you call this function? is it a GD resource? how have you loaded it?

Comment: @cmorrissey if GD resource is "imagecreatefrompng(...)" and of course I call it

Comment: add `imagealphablending($stamp, true);` after you call `imagecreatefrompng(...)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [imagecreatefrompng() Makes a black background instead of transparent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611852/imagecreatefrompng-makes-a-black-background-instead-of-transparent)

Comment: **duplicate** doesn't work too ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found the solution:

```
function ImageAddWatermark($im, $stamp, $onLeft, $onTop, $margin){

    if($onLeft){
        $orgX = $margin;
    } else {
        $orgX = imagesx($im)-$margin-imagesx($stamp);
    }

    if($onTop){
        $orgY = $margin;
    }else {
        $orgY = imagesy($im)-$margin-imagesy($stamp);
    }

    // creating a cut resource 
    $cut = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp)); 

    // copying relevant section from background to the cut resource 
    imagecopy($cut, $im, 0, 0, $orgX, $orgY, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp)); 

    // copying relevant section from watermark to the cut resource 
    imagecopy($cut, $stamp, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp)); 

    // insert cut resource to destination image 
    imagecopymerge($im, $cut, $orgX, $orgY, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp), 50); 

    return $im;
}
```