# Compress png and jpg Images during upload in PHP OOP

Tags: php, compression, image-compression

I have E-commerce website, In Users system, When user upload/update his/her profile picture then It should be compressed like: If real image size is 1MB then after uploading It should compress and save with 50kb minimum and 200kb maximum, I am doing it like this, **Here is my code:**

```
public function updateProfilePic($file, $userid) {
    $filename = $file['user_img']['name'];
    $filetmp = $file['user_img']['tmp_name'];
    $valid_ext = array('png', 'jpeg', 'jpg');
    $location = "user/profilepic/" . $filename;
    $file_extension = pathinfo($location, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $file_extensionstr = strtolower($file_extension);

    if(!empty($filename)){
        if (in_array($file_extensionstr, $valid_ext)) {
            //Here i am compressing image
            $this->compressImage($filetmp, $location, 9);
            return $this->updateProfilePicture($filename, $userid);
        } else {
            $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Invalid file type. You can upload only:-' . implode(', ', $valid_ext) . '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>';
            return $msg;
        }
    } else {
        $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Please upload your profile picture.<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>';
        return $msg;
    }
}

public function updateProfilePicture($filename, $userid){
    $update = "UPDATE users SET user_img = '$filename' WHERE user_id = '$userid'";
    $result = $this->db->update($update);
    if($result){
        $msg = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Profile picture uploaded successfully <a href="profile.php">Go back</a><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>';
        return $msg;
    } else {
        $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Error while uploading profile picture. Pleas try again!<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>';
        return $msg;
    }
}

public function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality) {
    $info = getimagesize($source);

    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg'){
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png'){
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
        imagealphablending($image, false);
        imagesavealpha($image, true);
    }

    imagepng($image, $destination, $quality);

}
```

You can see my `compressImage()` function, If i write `imagejpeg()` function then It compresses fine but in png (transparent) image, It saves with black background. So, I replaced with `imagepng()` function, But It is not compressing the image, It is increasing the size of the image after saving to `Database`, like my image size was `2 MB`, When I upload then It saves with size of `11 MB`. I don't know what happened.
**To be clear:** I just want to compress png and jpg images and transparent images should not save with black background. **Please help me**

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but as far as I recall you simply need to change `imagealphablending($image, false);` to `imagealphablending($image, true);`, however potentially you'll have to explicitly set a transparent background like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2611911/2989952

However, this doesn't really compress your images! You'll need some external programs to achieve what you want.

**JPEG:**

- [JPEG Optim](https://www.mankier.com/1/jpegoptim)
- [Mozilla JPEG Encoder Project](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg)

**PNG:**

- [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/)
- [pngquant](https://pngquant.org/)

If you're using Symfony as a base, you can easily use them thanks to [LiipImagineBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle), if not you can take a look at how they are doing it.

Furthermore I'd suggest using [webp](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp) which works well as a replacement for both JPEG as well as PNG images. For now you'll need both `.webp` as well as the old formats, as [not all browsers support webp yet](https://caniuse.com/#search=webp). You can conditionally serve images in Nginx using for example:

```
map $http_accept $img_suffix {
  "~*webp"  ".webp";
  "~*jxr"   ".jxr";
}

server {
    [...]

    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|png)$ {
        try_files   $uri$img_suffix $uri =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand brother, it goes from top of my head

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to compress images you must save them as JPG. PNG is lossless format so there is no room for saving space as PNG.

Unfortunately JPG cannot preserve transparency. Transparent pixels must be colored with some color.

I suggest you to draw white rectangle over whole image and then put your image over that, like:

```
$image= $info['mime'] == 'image/png'         // open origin image
  ? imagecreatefrompng($source)
  : imagecreatefromjpeg($source);  
$target= imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);           // open empty image with same size
$whitecolor= imagecolorallocate($target, 255, 255, 255);
imagefilledrectangle($target, 0,0, $width, $height, $whitecolor); // fill background
imagecopy($target, $image, $width,$height, 0,0, $width,$height);  // copy image over target
imagejpeg($target, $source);       // save as jpg
```

Comment: While this is technically true, you can still save some space on a png image (ex. OptiPNG or pngquant), however I personally would use webp, as it can work lossless and supports transparency while still saves space, compared to png.

Comment: what is $width and $height? I have no such variables in my function

Comment: Dimensions of your image, use imagesx() and imagesy() to find them, like this:
`$width= imagesx($image);
$height= imagesy($image);`